# Erro ao tentar usar um User Model Customizado. AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for

Tags: python-3.x, django

Olá.

Ao tentar criar e utilizar o UserModel Customizado ao executar o makemigrations ou mesmo executar o servidor obtenho o erro:

`AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'autenticacao.UsuarioCustom'`

Segue trecho dos meus códigos: **settings.py**, **forms.py** e o de model **usuario_custom.py**

**Settings**:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'apps.autenticacao',
]

# Estamos definindo para o Django o Modelo padrão para a autentição, removendo o default que é o User da app Auth
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'autenticacao.UsuarioCustom'
```

**Models**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class UsuarioCustomManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Classe criada para realizar a Administração do Model Usuário já que não usaremos o ambiente ADMIN padrão do Django
    """

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Função Privada para criar nossos usuários do sistema
        """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('O e-mail é obrigatório')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_istaff', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class UsuarioCustom(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuário'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'
        abstract = False
        swappable = 'UsuarioCustom'

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='E-mail', unique=True)
    fone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Telefone', max_length=15)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Membro da equipe', default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'fone']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    objects = UsuarioCustomManager()
```

**Forms**:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class UsuarioCustomCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'fone')
        labels = {'username': 'Username/E-mail'}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['username']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


class UsuarioCustomChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'fone')
```

- Pacotes instalados no projeto:

```
pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.5
coverage==5.0.4
cx-Oracle==6.4.1
Django==3.0.4
django-auth-ldap==2.1.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
model-mommy==2.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
python-ldap==3.2.0
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

Já pesquisei e tentei várias soluções mas não consigo sair deste erro!

Comment: O seu codigo não tem erro, pelo menos não do jeito que está aqui, faça um teste: não instale nada, so o django, inicie um projeto, crie uma app qualquer e cole o codigo do seu model da sua pergunta no arquivo models da app. Execute o a applicacao e entre no admin. Vc iniciou o sistema ja com o user customizado? Se não pode ser isso, tentar alterar o `user` com o sistema ja iniciado é fonte de problemas, a propria documentacao diz isso

Comment: @Sidon, obrigado pelas dicas, saí isolando as partes do projeto e descobrir que o erro estava apresentando porque dentro da área de API que desenvolvi com o rest_framework tinha uma consulta usando o User do contrib.auth, ao ajustar para o get_user_model() o problema deixou de existir. Obrigado.